# How to get array property values in a generated number input field

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, properties

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/3lly/pen/LYNzJwP

I have an array of objects:

```
   let product =  [
    {omschrijving:"Brood", waarde:1, aantal:3, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Brocolli", waarde:0.99, aantal:2, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Krentenbollen", waarde:1.20, aantal:4, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Noten", waarde:2.99, aantal:2, total:0}
    ]
```

And I generate a table, I added an extra column with a number input field. I want the property of aantal set in the value of the number input field.

With these loops (I did the loop again because a scoping issue?) I get the last value only in ALL of the fields. So they all fill in 2.

```
   var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(let j=0;j<elements.length;j++) {
                for(let i=0;i<product.length;i++) {                                       
                   let = elements[j].value = product[i].aantal;     
            }    
        }
```

The expected output is in the first input field it would be 3, the next, 2,4,2

I will also put the snippet here so you can see the result.( I know it is a mess right now)

UPDATE , I did get it finally, it took me hours I dont even really completely understand. But I gave a rowID with the generation of the row and compare it to that. I tried so many things. I have a lot to do on this code. Now to make it increment etc. etc.

Now my problem is that I cannot increment and update the value of products.aantal This so it can calculate the total. If I can get that to work I can fix the rest.

It somehow does not see the products.value in the loop of EentjeMeer Function.
Because that loop worked before I wanted to do the same loop but now of course just increment the "aantal" column. My head hurts :/ been at it for many hours today.

I added this, but I will update my snippet:

```
var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    schaap = [];
            for(let j=0;j<elements.length;j++) {
                inputID++;
                //console.log("de input ID" + inputID);
                //product.push({input: elements[j]});
             
                //console.log(schaap);
                for(let i=0;i<product.length;i++) {  
                    if ( rowID != inputID) {
                        rowID++

                        //schaap.push({aantal: product[i].aantal});
                        console.log( "inputID  " + inputID + "  en de ROW ID  " + rowID);
                        //console.log(schaap);
                        //index = product.findIndex(x => x.aantal[i] === elements[i]);
                  

                        if (rowID = product[i].aantal) { 


                            //index = product.findIndex(x => x.aantal === elements.input);
                            elements[i].value = product[i].aantal; 
                            //console.log("index" + index);
                        }

                    }
            }
        
        }
```

Thats what I added. Here below this was the code of my original questions:

```js
    
let myTable = document.querySelector('#table');
let rowID = 0;
let inputID = 0;
//Array met objecten erin {} staat voor een object
    let product =  [
    {omschrijving:"Brood", waarde:1, aantal:3, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Brocolli", waarde:0.99, aantal:2, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Krentenbollen", waarde:1.20, aantal:4, total:0},
    {omschrijving:"Noten", waarde:2.99, aantal:2, total:0}
    ]
///Update totals
    for(let i=0;i<product.length;i++)
{
  product[i].total = product[i].waarde*product[i].aantal;
    
}

const total = product.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
    return productCal.total + currentTotal
}, 0)
uitslag = total.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " + uitslag;
////Table
    let headers = ['Name', 'Prijs', 'Aantal', 'Totaal', 'Aanpassen'];

    
        let table = document.createElement('table');
        let headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
     
        headers.forEach(headerText => {
            let header = document.createElement('th');
            let textNode = document.createTextNode(headerText);
            header.appendChild(textNode);
            headerRow.appendChild(header);
        });
     
        table.appendChild(headerRow);

///////////td is column

    product.forEach(emp => {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        Object.values(emp).forEach(text => {
        
            //console.log("row" + rowID);
            let cell = document.createElement('td');
            let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);

            
            cell.appendChild(textNode);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        })
        input = document.createElement('input');
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        input.type = 'number';
        //input.value
        input.addEventListener('click', eentjeMeer() );      
        cell.appendChild(input);
        row.appendChild(cell);
/*
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "step";
        table.appendChild(input);
*/
        table.appendChild(row);
    });
  
        myTable.appendChild(table);
     
/////////////////////
/////////////////INPUTS AANPASSEN MET WAARDE VAN ARRAY////////////////////////////

var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); //misschien mot ik het in een array droppen
            for(let j=0;j<elements.length;j++) {
                inputID++;
                //console.log("de input ID" + inputID);
                //product.push({input: elements[j]});
             
                //console.log(schaap);
                for(let i=0;i<product.length;i++) {  
                    if ( rowID != inputID) {
                        rowID++

                        //schaap.push({aantal: product[i].aantal});
                        console.log( "inputID  " + inputID + "  en de ROW ID  " + rowID);
                        //console.log(schaap);
                        //index = product.findIndex(x => x.aantal[i] === elements[i]);
                  

                        if (rowID = product[i].aantal) { //hier GAAT IETS GOED ALS laatst op 22:22 HIJ DOET DE LAATSTE NIET WHY???


                            //index = product.findIndex(x => x.aantal === elements.input);
                            elements[i].value = product[i].aantal; 
                            //console.log("index" + index);
                        }
                              
                  

                    }

            }
        
        }

        //product[i].total = product[i].waarde*product[i].aantal;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

for(let j=0;j<product.length;j++) {
    //let row = document.createElement('tr');
}

function updateTable() {
            test = [];
        
            b1 = document.getElementById('naam').value;
            b2 = document.getElementById('prijs').value;
            b3 = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        
        test.push({omschrijving:b1, waarde:b2, aantal:b3, total:0});

        for(let i=0;i<test.length;i++)
        {
        test[i].total = test[i].waarde*test[i].aantal;
        }

        test.forEach(emp => {
            let row = document.createElement('tr');

            Object.values(emp).forEach(text => {
                let cell = document.createElement('td');
                let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
                cell.appendChild(textNode);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            })

            table.appendChild(row);
         
        });

            myTable.appendChild(table);

            //console.log(product);

/////////////////////////totaal na update WORDT AFGEROND DOOR PARSEINT?!?!?!
            const total0 = test.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
                return productCal.total + currentTotal
            }, 0)
            
            console.log("total0 =  " + total0);
            yo = total0.toFixed(2);
            yo1 = Number.parseInt(yo) + Number.parseInt(uitslag);
            document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " + yo1;
            console.log(yo);
        }
    
        function eentjeMeer(){

                
    var elements = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); //misschien mot ik het in een array droppen
    for(let j=0;j<elements.length;j++) {
        inputID++;
        //console.log("de input ID" + inputID);
        //product.push({input: elements[j]});
    
        //console.log(schaap);
        for(let i=0;i<product.length;i++) {  
            if ( rowID != inputID) {
                rowID++

                //schaap.push({aantal: product[i].aantal});

                //console.log(schaap);
                //index = product.findIndex(x => x.aantal[i] === elements[i]);
        

                if (rowID = product[i].aantal)  { 
                    console.log(product[i].aantal); //het doet het wel nu....iets met inputID denk ik



                    objIndex = product.findIndex((obj => obj.aantal == rowID));
                    //product[i].aantal.name = elements[i].value;

                    testje = product[i].aantal;

                    //elements[i].value = inputID;
                    //inputID = product[i].aantal;
                    //product[i].aantal = elements[i].value; 
                    //console.log(elements[i].value);
                    //console.log(product);
                    //console.log("index" + index);
                }
                    
        

            }

    }

    }       
        };
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
 
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
 
button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
 
#table {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
 
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

#totaal {

    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
    <title>Boodschappenlijst</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Boodschappenlijst </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="table"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Naam</p>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="naam" /><br />
        <p>Aantal</p>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="qty" /><br />
        <p>Prijs</p>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="prijs" /><br/><br />
    <input type="button" value="Add Product" onclick="updateTable()" id="add"><br /><br />
    <div id="totaal"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is something with a proper if statement but I am working on it :) i have been stuck for a bit too long now

Comment: I feel I never get any answers, am I doing something wrong ? Anyways I now try to give an incremental variable with the input fields and the rows made. So maybe thats it. I hope so.

Comment: So with a lot of effort I finally got the values in the input fields, I do not even know how but I will put it in the question here. Now to be able to get it to increment and update, the code needs to be clean. The code needs to be divided into more event listeners and way better in { usage